# In a sugar such as a disaccharide are both ends of the sugar known as reducing ends?

Tags: biochemistry

For example, in maltose (a disaccharide of glucose monomers) are both of the ends either side able to be opened to form an aldehyde group?

Answer (score 1):

No, in dissacharides the reducing end is situated only on one monosaccharide which is having free anomeric carbon. This carbon does not take part in glycosidic bond formation and can form open chain.

[image: Figure showing reducing end in maltose]

[image: Figure showing anomeric carbon of maltose]

Check out:
https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Sacramento_City_College/SCC%3A_Chem_309_-_General%2C_Organic_and_Biochemistry_(Bennett)/Text/14%3A_Carbohydrates/14.6%3A_Disaccharides

Comment: Your answer would be better if it indicated the reducing position in the monosaccharides and the disaccheride and did not contain material largely  irrelevant to the question. Perhaps you could consider drawing a diagram of your own.

Comment: okay..will do that